# qt resources qrc not being found

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I´m trying to load the following file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/mike">
    <file alias="mike.json">mike.json</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

with

```
QFile file(":/mike/mike.json");
```

But it does not work.

So I moved

```
<qresource prefix="/mike">
    <file alias="mike.json">mike.json</file>
</qresource>
```

to another .qrc file. Then it worked.

Is there some way do debug in order to check if at least the prefix is being created?

I'm loading it from

```
SOURCES +=  \
    $$PWD/form.cpp 

HEADERS  += \
    $$PWD/form.h

RESOURCES = $$PWD/mike.qrc
```

and .cpp and .h files are available. I do not understand why `mike.qrc` seems not being parsed.

Comment: did you try to use `QFile file("qrc:/mike/mike.json");` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way do debug in order to check if at least the prefix is being created?

Method 1: Use [GammaRay](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/gammaray/), it can show your resource tree.

Method 2: In your app, use a recursive QDirIterator starting from `:/`, and dump the file names as found.

Comment: Using Method 2 I found the resource file set in the .qrc file isn't being loaded. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Do you mean that it's NOT in the tree listed by that dir iterator? (Are you sure it's recursive?)